# Need help for SQL statement s to combine 2 tables

Tags: sql

Good Day Everyone,

I kindly need some help for combining to 2 tables using using SQL SELECT ALL

Table accounts

```
ID| USNM | PSSWRD | DEPT | TYPE | FNAME | LNAME<br>
 1 | user1 | 1234 | fin  | user |  Juan | Cruz<br>
2  | user2 | 5678 | it | sup   |John | Cross
```

Table adminAccounts

```
ID | USNM | PSSWRD | DEPT | TYPE | FNAME | LNAME <br>
1  | admin| admin  | all  | admin| Boss  | Owner <br>
```

Desired Output after joining 2 tables

Table accounts

```
ID | USNM | PSSWRD | DEPT | TYPE | FNAME | LNAME <br>
1  | user1| 1234   | fin  | user |  Juan | Cruz <br>
2  | user2| 5678   | it   | sup  |  John | Cross <br>
3  | admin| admin  | all  | admin| Boss  | Owner <br>
```

I am really clueless for this kind of SQL statement because some of the reference online are combining 2 tables with different columns. I would really appreciate the help for providing the SQL statement for Selecting 2 tables for this basic problem.

I am currently working on a inventory system with login capability using account per department.

using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM accounts", con))

Comment: Use a `UNION` to join two tables

Comment: Are you storing password as plain text?

Comment: @B001ᛦ, yes sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Union Select.

```
SELECT * FROM t1

UNION

SELECT * FROM t2
```

Union combines the results of two select statements. It is important that they have to have identical columns. See [W3 Schools SQL Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Sir, thank you very much, I now understand the basic logic for using this statement.

Comment: Sir, how about if I use UNION without duplicating the 1 ID from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

you can use union

```
select ID,USNM ,PSSWRD ,DEPT ,TYPE , FNAME ,LNAME from accounts
union all
select ID,USNM ,PSSWRD ,DEPT ,TYPE , FNAME ,LNAME from adminAccounts
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNION [ALL]` might seem like the obvious solution, but it doesn't re-set the id column.

So, you need `row_number()` as well:

```
select row_number() over (order by which, id) as id,
       USNM, PSSWRD, DEPT, TYPE, FNAME, LNAME
from ((select t1.*, 1 as which
       from table1 t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.*, 2 as which
       from table2 t2
      )
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to remember this:

a `JOIN` adds columns from another table to your query result

a `UNION` adds rows from another table to query result

[image]
[image]